# How to update option field in database on clicking the publish button in customizer

Tags: php, theme-customizer, options

I want to use `update_option('option_name', $new_array)` to change the database option value when user clicks the publish button in wordpress theme customizer. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When 'publish' is clicked in customizer, the option 'theme_mods_THEMENAMED' is updated.  An function/action could be added See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/ on the wordpress actions

add_option_(option_name)  and

update_option_(option_name)

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions.   The new function could then save what ever option you want to update.

Comment: I want to make sections sortable, using jquery .sortable function. but changing just the sections position doesn't trigger the disabled "publish" button. First i need to enable it upon change of sections order. how do i enable it?  secondly i'm retrieving the new section order using .sortable('serialize) on js file and passing to a php file where i want to use update_option('option_name', $newOrder) to update the option table when user clicks the active "publish" button. Keep in mind that it has nothing to do with settings/controls attached with sections.

Comment: and i'm populating the sections  using foreach loop on the retrieved array from that option table

Comment: Hi Seeker, that sounds like quite a different question from the first one you asked.  I suggest write it up separately and clearly with all that you have tried so far and tag it 'jquery', 'js'.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but in summary all i want to know is if there is any hook that triggers when publish button is clicked? so that i can hook a function which updates the database.

Comment: Hi seeker, the hooks that trigger when theme mods are updated (ie when the publish button is clicked after updates are made) are in the answer above, and yers you can add a function to those hooks to update the database just after it updates the theme mods option.

Comment: thank you, as you know usually the publish button is deactivated, and only gets updated upon changes of values in controls. As no values are being changed here (only section's position), is there any function to activate and deactivate the publish button manually ?